# how to count specific items in array in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, collections

Let's say i have array of any object below , I'm looking for a way to count items in the array as following:

```
var OSes = ["iOS", "Android", "Android","Android","Windows Phone", 25]
```

Is there a short way for swift to do something like this below  ?

```
Oses.count["Android"]   // 3
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A fast, compact and elegant way to do it is by using the `reduce` method:

```
let count = OSes.reduce(0) { $1 == "Android" ? $0 + 1 : $0 }
```

It's more compact than a `for` loop, and faster than a `filter`, because it doesn't generate a new array.

The `reduce` method takes an initial value, 0 in our case, and a closure, applied to each element of the array.

The closure takes 2 parameters:

- the value at the previous iteration (or the initial value, 0 in our case)
- the array element for the current iteration

The value returned by the closure is used as the first parameter in the next iteration, or as the return value of the `reduce` method when the last element has been processed

The closure simply checks if the current element is `Android`:

- if not, it returns the aggregate value (the first parameter passed to the closure)
- if yes, it returns that number plus one

Comment: This is a well-written explanation of `reduce()`. +1

Comment: I always use `for case` syntax to deal with count specific items in Array. Your method is more swifty.

Answer (score 7):

It's pretty simple with `.filter`:

```
OSes.filter({$0 == "Android"}).count // 3
```

Comment: `reduce` is more performant, but I prefer `filter().count` for readability.

Comment: Yup, always compromise between readability and speed / effectivity. Depends on underlying data and amount of them. If it doesn't hurt, I do prefer readability.

Comment: There's interesting [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31231548/581190) from @AirspeedVelocity regarding performance.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5** with [count(where:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3126943-count)

```
let countOfAndroid = OSes.count(where: { $0 == "Android" })
```

**Swift 4 or less** with [filter(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/3018365-filter)

```
let countOfAndroid = OSes.filter({ $0 == "Android" }).count
```

Comment: `count(where:)` was briefly with us in Swift 5, but sadly it was removed because of conflicts with the type checking system.

Comment: This Swift 5.0 feature was withdrawn in beta testing because it was causing performance issues for the type checker. Hopefully it will come back in time for Swift 5.1, perhaps with a new name to avoid problems. https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/126/whats-new-in-swift-5-0