# Laziness in Swift

Tags: swift, lazy-evaluation, swift2

Why is `lazy` used here?

```
extension SequenceType {
    func mapSome<U>(transform: Generator.Element -> U?) -> [U] {
        var result: [U] = []
        for case let x? in lazy(self).map(transform) {
            result.append(x)
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

this extension takes a transformation function that returns an optional, and returns an array of only those values that weren’t transformed into nil

Why not just use `self.map(transform)` ? is laziness necessary here?

Comment: By the way, `flatMap<U>(transform: Generator.Element -> U?) -> [U]` is now available in the Swift 2 standard library :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It avoids the creation of an intermediate array.

```
self.map(transform)
```

returns an *array* containing the results of the transformation of
*all* sequence elements, which would then be traversed to build the
resulting array with the non-nil elements.

```
lazy(self).map(transform)
```

is a *sequence* of the transformed elements, which is then 
iterated over to get the non-nil elements. The transformed elements
are computed during the enumeration.  (Each call to `next()`
on the lazy sequence produces one element by transforming the next
element of the original sequence.)

Both methods work. The lazy method would probably perform better
for large sequences, but that can depend on many factors (the size
of the array, whether the elements are value or reference types,
how costly it is to copy array elements etc). For small arrays
the lazy method would probably be slower due to the additional
overhead. In a concrete application, profiling with Instruments would
help to decide which method to use.

Comment: My (admittedly informal) performance tests suggest that the lazy and non-lazy perform identically for small arrays, but that lazy does give a modest edge on larger ones, so it’s worth including (especially in a library function like this). Interestingly, `flatMap`, which as of 2.0 now does this same logic, performs worse than both.

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity: That is interesting, thank you for the feedback.

Comment: Interestingly I've got the opposite result!? See my answer below.

Answer (score 7):

As Martin R mentioned `lazy()` avoids the creation of an intermediate array. However if I compare the execution time of the function on arrays of different sizes you find that `lazy()` is "only" 10% faster.

Interestingly, you find that `lazy()` is for arrays with less than 200 elements up to 2 times as fast and gets with more elements almost equally fast as the function without the conversion (10% faster).

(Tested with Xcode 6.4 and Xcode 7 with global functions and protocol extension in a Playground as (compiled) source files)

So `lazy()` would rather be used for `Sequences` where you don't know if it is finite. Then, for loops are likely used with `break` or `return`:

```
for element in lazy(sequence).map{ ... } {
    if element == 1000 {
        break
    }
    // use element
}
```

If you call map on a infinite `Sequence` (like 1,2,3...) the execution would also be infinite. With `lazy()` the transformation and the execution get "delayed" thus you can handle "big" and infinite sequences more efficiently if you break out of the loop before the last element.