# Swift – How to find out if a string contains several identical characters?

Tags: swift

Here's a simple code that let us find out if a string contains a `dot` characters (we don't know how many, we just know that it contains it):

```
var number: String = "3.14"

if number.contains(".") {
    print("The string contains a dot character")
} else {
    print("There's no dot character")
}
```

But imagine a situation where user wrongly puts 2 or 3 dots in a line, like this:

```
var number: String = "3...14"
```

**How to check whether a string contains one `dot` or several ones?**

**How to count all the dots in the string?**

Comment: `number.contains(".")` does return true if the string contains one, two or 100 dots. – And what does “several similar characters” mean exactly?

Comment: A String is a collection of Characters, therefore the methods from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31194938/how-to-count-specific-items-in-array-in-swift can be used here as well.

Comment: You still did not clarify what “similar characters” are.

Comment: Martin, I fixed the heading.

Comment: @MartinR, do you know what happened to `count(where:)`?  We had it temporarily in Swift 5.

Comment: @vacawama: See https://forums.swift.org/t/require-parameter-names-when-referencing-to-functions/27048: "This proposal was ultimately accepted in time for Swift 5, but sadly had to be reverted because it was causing issues with the type checker."

Comment: @MartinR, thank you! I really appreciate that you followed up on my question. It's a shame the type inference system got in the way, but that’s some tricky code to get right. It seems to me that they could have renamed it to `countElements(where:)` instead of dropping it entirely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`filter(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2893557-filter) on the string and [`count`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/3003522-count) to get the number of dots:

```
let str = "3..14"

switch str.filter({ $0 == "." }).count {
case 0:
    print("string has no dots")
case 1:
    print("string has 1 dot")
default:
    print("string has 2 or more dots")
}
```